# How to find the lowest possible combination of keys within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that will always have 6 keys: `var ary = [5,10,28,50,56,280]`.
I have a variable defined as `limit` I want to check it against.

I want to find the lowest possible combination or sum of keys from this array that is above `limit`. We'll call this `result`.

A bit of constraints I am trying to work within:

**1** `result` can be a single key itself:
Such as If `limit = 0` the lowest possible combination or sum of keys should default to the lowest key it can find which would be `ary[ 0 ]`. in this case or `5`.

**2** `result` can be a combination of any keys:
If `limit = 11`, `result` would = `ary[ 0 ] + ary[ 1 ]` ( 5 + 10 ). which would be `15`.

**3** And lastly, `result` can be above the greatest sum of `ary`:
`result = 5 + 10 + 28 + 50 + 56 + 280; // equals 429` In this case limit would be `430`

**Note:**  Any key can be repeated as many times as it has to before it surpasses `result`.

My attempts in progress:

```js
function add(a, b) { //add all keys in array
    return a + b;
}

var combine = function(a, min) { //find all combinations of array
    var fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
        if (n == 0) {
            if (got.length > 0) {
                all[all.length] = got;
            }
            return;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
            fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
        }
        return;
    }
    var all = [];
    for (var i = min; i < a.length; i++) {
        fn(i, a, [], all);
    }
    all.push(a);
    return all;
}

var subsets = combine([5,10,28,50,56,280], 1);
var limit = 11;

for( var i = 0; i < subsets.length; i++ ){
  document.write('combination: ' + subsets[ i ] + ' sum: ' + subsets[ i ].reduce(add, 0) + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Will the array always have 6 items, or do you have to allow for efficiency in processing much larger arrays? What if `limit` is higher than the largest possible sum? Return `undefined`, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn For the purposes of this small program it will always have 6 items. There is no largest possible sum because that number is infinite, as keys can be reused over and over again. I'll update my question.

Comment: This looks like an interview question, and the solution can be based off of the same idea as the `max sum subarray`. On Stackoverflow, it's important that you show some code that you tried and what progress you made.

Comment: @MouadDebbar Thanks for the feedback. Not an interview question but I'll update my attempts as I am still learning much about JS.

Comment: This is a variation of Subset Sum problem. Please refer http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/ and this should help to some extent

Comment: What would be the result if the limit is 44? Would it be `[50]` or `[10, 28]`?

Comment: @PeterLeger The result if limit was 44 should be the lowest key or combination of keys the function can find that sits **above** 44. So the answer should be 48. 28 + 10 + 10

Comment: @carb0nshel1 so any key may be repeated while finding the combinations?

Comment: @kukkuz Yes. I'll update my question. Any key should be allowed to be repeated until it surpasses `result`. Of course, it should still be the lowest possible value to surpass `result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this works. Can you provide more test cases? The expected `429 > 434` from your answer *should* be `429 > 430`, right?

```js
var findLowest = function(arr, limit) {
    if (limit < arr[0]) return arr[0];

    // If there's a number in our arr that's higher than the limit,
    // this is the initial benchmark
    var bestCandidate = Infinity,
        maxIndex = arr.findIndex(v => v > limit);

    if (maxIndex !== -1) {
        bestCandidate = arr[maxIndex] - limit;
        arr = arr.slice(0, maxIndex);
    }

    // Calculate remainders, call this method recursively for all remainders
    var diffs = arr.map(v => limit % v);

    var finalDiffs = diffs.map(v => findLowest(arr, v) - v);
    
    return limit + Math.min(bestCandidate, finalDiffs.sort()[0]);
    
};

var prepareData = function(arr) {
    return arr
        // Remove duplicates of nrs in array
        .reduce((res, v) => {
            var needed = !res.length || res.every(r => v % r);
            return needed ? res.concat(v) : res;
        }, [])

        // Generate each combination (length * length - 1)
        .reduce((res, v, i, all) => {
            return res.concat(v).concat(all.slice(i + 1).map(v2 => v + v2));
        }, [])
        
        // Sort lowest first
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

var data = [5,10,28,50,56,280];
var testCases = [
    [data, 5, 10],
    [data, 11, 15],
    [data, 25, 28],
    [data, 50, 53],
    [data, 55, 56],
    [data, 1, 5],
    [data, 281, 282], // 9 * 28 + 5 * 6
    [[50, 60, 110], 161, 170]
];

testCases.forEach(tc => {
    var prep = prepareData(tc[0]);
    var result = findLowest(prep, tc[1]);

    if (result !== tc[2]) {
      console.log("Limit: ", tc[1]);
      console.log("Expected: ", tc[2]);
      console.log("Result: ", result);
      console.log("----");
    }
});
```

*Note:* my current try is recursive, which might not be ideal... If it passes all your tests, we could rewrite it to not be recursive.

Comment: You are right. 429 would = 430. This is the first to past all of my test cases so far. Very solid code. Doing a little more testing and tweaking it to show the numbers it is using to add. Thanks :)

Comment: I feel like there are still some cases I didn't cover, but can't think of the right test to make it fail... Fun but hard problem to solve!

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to edit your code so it shows what numbers it is adding so I have a better idea what is going on.

Comment: A limit of `500` produces a result of `501`. Which I'm pretty sure is impossible to get by summing up any of those numbers, repeating or not.

Comment: 89 x 5 + 56 = 501

Comment: Where do you get the 89 from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126670/discussion-between-carb0nshel1-and-user3297291).

Comment: I see how you got 89. 56 + 28 + 5. This function does what I asked. Thank you.

Comment: Great to see the question solved - +1. @user3297291 It would be nice to add an explanation now too as I find it hard to understand the magic

Comment: @user3297291 Yeah, it would be much appreciated if you could somehow show what numbers you are adding. I've tried to break apart your code and fail :(. Also here is a question related to this one that shows what I am eventually trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255189/a-counter-keeping-track-of-multiple-values-inside-an-array

Comment: I tried to tackle this question without any theoretical knowledge about the problem; now I see this link in the other answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem Seems to me that you should port the python code to javascript to get the best result. My approach kind of resembles a "greedy" one, according to the article. I'll see if I can edit it to log the combination though. Also, note that I've included a test that still fails: 181 -> (28 * 4) + (5 * 34)

Answer (score 0):

So here is a solution using nested `forEach` loops:

```js
var ary = [5, 10, 28, 50, 56, 280];

function lowestSum(limit) {
  var thisArg = {sum: 0};

  ary.forEach(function(ele1, index1) {
    if (ele1 > limit && (ele1 < this.sum || this.sum === 0))
      this.sum = ele1;
    ary.forEach(function(ele2, index2) {
      if (index1 !== index2 && ele1 + ele2 > limit 
          && (ele1 + ele2 < this.sum || this.sum === 0)) {
        this.sum = ele1 + ele2;
      }
    }, this);
  }, thisArg);
  return thisArg.sum;
}

console.log(lowestSum(6));
console.log(lowestSum(11));
console.log(lowestSum(27));
console.log(lowestSum(28));
```

Comment: I overlooked this. Doing a bit more testing. Thanks already though this is brilliant.

Comment: Still fails in certain situations though. I'm editing my question again and searching for better ways. You came very close.

Comment: Any high numbers like `400` return a `result` that's off like `0`

Comment: Another question: if `limit` is say 500, is the `result` will be 429?

Comment: No, the result should always be **above** the limit.

Comment: There are a lot of conditions at play here...  I'll have another go tomorrow morning.

Comment: Sorry got a bit confused there, will have a look later on, thanks!

Comment: @ downvoter please come to light and give us a reason?

Comment: you may find interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255189/a-counter-keeping-track-of-multiple-values-inside-an-array

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small array and thus don't care much about efficiency then you can do the following.

1. generate candidate pairs
2. sort the candidate pairs by their sum
3. loop through the sorted pairs until you find one over your limit

   ```
   var limit = 39;
   var ary = [5,10,28,50,56,280];

   function getLowestCombinationOverLimit(ary, limit) {
        var i, j, p;
        var pairs = [];
        for(i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
            for(j = i + 1; j < ary.length; j++) {
                pairs.push({x:ary[i], y:ary[j]});
            }
        }
        pairs.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a.x + a.y) - (b.x + b.y);
        });
        for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            p = pairs[i];
            if (p.x + p.y > limit) {
                return p;
            }    
        }
        return null;
    }

    console.log(getLowestCombinationOverLimit(ary, limit));
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I'm testing this with different values for limit and it doesn't seem like it works every time. I will update my question in case you misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

- Sort the array
- Iterate the array largest value first, reducing the most closest value from the limit until limit goes below 0

```js
function calcSumOfLowestComponents(ary,limit){
  ary.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  var safeCount = 0;

  var components = [];
  var remainder = limit + 1;
  while (remainder > 0){
    var found = false;
    for( var i = ary.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i-- ){
      if (remainder > ary[ i ]){
        var closeHigh = i != ary.length - 1 ? ary[i + 1] : ary[i];
        var closeLow = ary[i];
        if (closeHigh - remainder > remainder - closeLow){
          components.push(closeLow);
          remainder -= closeLow;  
        }
        else{
          components.push(closeHigh);
          remainder -= closeHigh;  
        }
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found && remainder > 0){
      components.push(ary[ 0 ]); 
      remainder -= ary[ 0 ];
    }
    
    if (safeCount > 1000){
      break;
    }
    safeCount++;
  }
  return { total : limit + 1 - remainder, components : components};
}

function dumpData(array,value){
  var result = calcSumOfLowestComponents(array,value);
  document.write("Value = " + value + " Total = " + result.total + " Components " + result.components + "</br>");
}

var array = [5,10,28,50,56,280];
dumpData(array,2);
dumpData(array,5);
dumpData(array,11);
dumpData(array,25);
dumpData(array,28);
dumpData(array,50);
dumpData(array,55);
dumpData(array,281);
dumpData(array,429);
```

Result

```
Value = 2 Total = 5 Components 5
Value = 5 Total = 10 Components 5,5
Value = 11 Total = 15 Components 10,5
Value = 25 Total = 28 Components 28
Value = 28 Total = 33 Components 28,5
Value = 50 Total = 55 Components 50,5
Value = 55 Total = 56 Components 56
Value = 281 Total = 285 Components 280,5
Value = 429 Total = 430 Components 280,56,56,28,10
```

Comment: Checking this in multiple use cases...looks promising.

Comment: This is flawed. If I input the value `25`, instead of getting `30` I get 43. Working on tweaking your code.

Comment: Too late to edit my last comment but if I input a value of `25` I should get `28`. Not `30`.

Comment: Updated the answer to address the 25

Comment: Thanks for edit. A similar issue happens when the result is `33` instead of returning `35` ( 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 ), it returns `38`. I'm looking into first finding all combinations of the array using something like this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array. Also fixed an error in my question. Like you show 429 would equal 430.

Comment: Shouldn't 33 result in 10+10+10+5?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. The result should be `35` and it should be arrived at using 10 + 10 + 10 + 5 because that is the fastest way to get there. PS. I updated my question and trying an approach that cycles through every single combination in the array and adds keys until it surpasses the `limit`

Comment: See the linked question if you still have interest.